# What's the difference between "≡" and "≣"?

Tags: notation, terminology

What's the difference between "≡" ("identical to") and "≣" ("strictly equivalent to")?

"Strictly equivalent to" ("≣") is [UTF character 2263](http://graphemica.com/%E2%89%A3), classified in the Mathematical Operators block.

Comment: I never heard of "≣" ("strictly equivalent to"). Where did it occur?

Comment: Ditto. Never heard of the four-bar version. Unless it means you have a good Wi-Fi signal.

Comment: @martycohen It's UTF character 2263. See the link I added to my answer.

Comment: this looks more like a Unicode question, rather than a math question. might be the unicode people had a slot for a character in which they didn't know what to put, or had some leftover bars to dispose of.

Comment: $\equiv$ and similar variations are a generic symbols used to notate an equivalence relation.  $=$ is the specific equivalence relation "equals" that we are used to with sets and natural numbers and by extension is also the symbol used for equality of rational, real, complex numbers etc...  For more information on the definition of a *specific* equivalence relation, you will need to provide information about that specific equivalence relation.  There are too many to provide the definitions of every one.

Comment: @Mirko So "strictly equivalent to" doesn't mean anything specific in a mathematical context?

Comment: as others above, I had never heard of or seen it before. One might conceivably want to, or need to use it, if in the same paper or proof, or argument you need to use several different equivalence relations, and you risk running out of symbols for them. Can't quite envision this to happen in practice

Comment: you might want to google "tex cookbook" and take a look into it, e.g. at https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~fei/Tutorials/TeX%2520cookbook.pdf in particular on p.7 where there is a number of equivalence relation symbols, the one you ask about does not appear there.

Comment: And I've never seen $\equiv$ to mean is identical to.  I've always seen $=$ means is strictly identical to and $\equiv$ to mean is equivalent to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have two expressions $X$ and $Y$. A way of expressing that they are equivalent, or equal to each other by definition, is as follows: $$X\equiv Y.\tag1$$ However, the symbol $\equiv$ also denotes *congruence*, e.g. $p^2\equiv 1\pmod 6$, so using the symbol for two different circumstances can cause some confusion. Thus, to denote $(1)$, some write that $$X:= Y\quad\text{ or }\quad X\triangleq Y\quad\text{ or }\quad X\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} Y.$$ But, there is also another (but less common) variation, namely, $$X\operatorname*{\equiv}\limits^{\underline{ \ \ \ }}Y\quad\text{ or with a different typeset, }\quad X\,\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\shortparallel\shortparallel}Y.$$ The "quadruple bar" is not used to denote congruence.

---

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058596/in-plain-language-whats-the-difference-between-two-things-that-are-equivalent?rq=1) might serve useful.

Comment: I noticed too, this “strictly equivalent” symbol (≣). Please, can you tell more about it?

Comment: @Hibou57 Another related Math.SE post is over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462829/how-to-represent-a-logic-equivalence) (see Doug Spoonwood's answer) which discusses about notating "equality" in propositional logic. But I first came across this "quadruple" bar on a PDF which, in hindsight, I should have attached to my answer. There's nothing too significant about it though, apart from its rare use, albeit having a somewhat intuitive meaning (to me at least).